# Why is my background color not being applied?

Tags: css

I'm trying to work out why my `background-color` isn't showing up. I'm guessing it has something to do with the float, but am not exactly sure why or what is causing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/K4Sw9/

Comment: the social icons are float, so the parent has no content/box

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer first?  Using "css float background" brings back a *lot* of relevant results.

Comment: The first result was from 2012, the second, from 2013. I could have eventually figured it out, but who knows what has changed from 2012 and the first couple weren't really relevant to my unique situation. I prefer asking here so there is an updated answer that may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

before closing `#header-social`.

Comment: +1 just clear http://jsfiddle.net/K4Sw9/2/ ... no need height remove that option. Use height is fake the solution not the right way to go.

Comment: Got it, thanks! clearing did the trick.

Comment: @Danko I agree with you. Edited that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#header-social-inner:after {
   display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';    
}
```

You can add a pseduo element with clear both so you don't have to change your markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Nz3z/

Actually, I like this better:

```
#header-social:last-child:after {
   display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Nz3z/1/

Answer (score -1):

just give a height. like this:

```
#header-social {
    background-color: #111;
    height: 125px;
}
```